# How to copy and move data in Spreadsheet using a Formula/Script

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I used this code in excel to move data when it came in

E.G. if in cell A1 the word "Greg" appeared, data from B1 would move to F1

I need to know how to do this in spreadsheets

Help is appreciated

Cheers

Below is VBA Version

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'   Check to see if a value in your pre-determined range is being changed
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A5000")) Is Nothing Then
'       Check to see if "Greg" is one of the words being entered into the cell
        If InStr(Target, "Greg") > 0 Then
'           If so, then move entry from column B in that same row to column F
            Cells(Target.Row, "F") = Cells(Target.Row, "B")
            Cells(Target.Row, "B").ClearContents
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to detect whether the cell `A1` contains the text `GREG` you can use the `FIND` function:

```
=FIND("GREG", A1)
```

This will return the position of the text `GREG` within `A1`.

However, if the text is not found it returns an error, so you can combined `FIND` with `ISERROR` to handle the situation when the text is not found:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("GREG", A1))=TRUE,"",B1)
```

Simply place the above formula in your `F1` cell and copy and paste to all the other cells in the `F` column and you should then see the content of `B1` where `GREG` is contained in `A1`, or blank if not.

Comment: May I recommend `SEARCH` in lieu of `FIND`? `FIND` is case sensitive and will not work if the cell has "Greg" as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Thanks but how would i add other names to the same formula, James, Kev Dave ETC